# IdentityServer4 Show Access Denied page after login

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

There are 3 applications in the system: IdentityServer, Jelly SPA app, and KenX SPA app. 
There are two kinds of users: Visitor and Client. A user has type is Client cannot access to Jelly SPA app.

The scenario is when the user goes to the Jelly SPA app, it redirects to IdentityServer to require a login, after login, if user type is Client, IdentityServer shows the Access Denied page and stops redirect back to the Jelly SPA app. Currently, I cannot implement it, the code shows the Access Denied page looks like this:

```
if (user.Type == AppIdentityType.Client)
{
      return AccessDenied();
}
```

Even the code runs fine, it cannot show Access Denied and immediately redirects to Jelly SPA App.

My question is how can we stop redirects back to Jelly SPA App if business logic is not passed. In this case, is User Type is the Client. Can we customize the Authorization Code flow?

Comment: Which tutorial you followed to write this code? It looks like  a complex process in it. Did you debug your app and find any issue about the redirection? With the information you provided, it seems that what you want is a sample, but not troubleshoting.

Comment: @TinyWang I just read the login flow and authorization flow. I tried with endpoint access denied, this endpoint can be accessed from the public, it works in preventing redirect to the application if the logic is not passed but failed in case of user already logged in. I think need to hook up to authorization flow to modify.

Comment: Did you get any break on this case sir?

Comment: @TinyWang, I did that by implementing ICustomTokenRequestValidator. There are two gateway of checking, if the user is not authorized, it will be in AccountController or ExternalController, if the user is authorized, it will be in TokenRequestValidator. I'm struggling to display an error message when /token endpoint returns an error from angualar-oidc-client package but successfully to not issue token for the specified client if validation is not passed.